# Use value from sibling with condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I've been trying to get this to work for quite some time and I know I still have to watch the 22hrs I have left on my Udemy xsl class but it's not an inspiring teacher..

I want to search for a value higher up in the xml tree and use that value 'x times'. I want the value of /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT44/ABLAD

where /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN = /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/VBELN

and use that in an extra /SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/ABLAD element

1 - I have as input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287203</TKNUM>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0001</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>            
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

2 - I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287203</TKNUM>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0001</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>2</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
            <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>001</QUALI>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
               <QUALI>002</QUALI>
               <ABLAD>3</ABLAD>
            </E1EDT44>
            <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            </E1EDT01>            
         </E1EDK33>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
            ***<ABLAD>3</ABLAD>***
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
            ***<ABLAD>1</ABLAD>***
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
            ***<ABLAD>2</ABLAD>***
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

3 - My xsl is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<!--    <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[(VBELN= following-sibling::E1EDT01/VBELN) or (VBELN= ../following-sibling::E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN)]"/> -->

          <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDL20/VBELN"> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="stopno" select="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[VBELN=VBELN]/parent::node()/E1EDT44/ABLAD"/>
        <ABLAD><xsl:value-of select="$stopno" /></ABLAD> 
      </xsl:template> 
        
   <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
     </xsl:template> 
    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

4 - I get

```
<SHPMNT05>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
      <TKNUM>0000287203</TKNUM>
      <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
        <TSNUM>0001</TSNUM>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>001</QUALI>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>002</QUALI>
          <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
          <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
        </E1EDT01>
      </E1EDK33>
      <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
        <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>001</QUALI>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>002</QUALI>
          <OBLAD>2</OBLAD>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
          <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
        </E1EDT01>
      </E1EDK33>
      <E1EDK33 SEGMENT="1">
        <TSNUM>0002</TSNUM>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>001</QUALI>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT44 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>002</QUALI>
          <OBLAD>3</OBLAD>
        </E1EDT44>
        <E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
          <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
        </E1EDT01>
      </E1EDK33>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0081018666</VBELN>
        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
      </E1EDL20>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
      </E1EDL20>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0081018668</VBELN>
        <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
      </E1EDL20>
    </E1EDT20>
  </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Do I need to use a 'for each' or something?

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: `E1EDT01[VBELN=VBELN]` usually doesn't make sense and rather wants `E1EDT01[VBELN=current()/VBELN]` or the use of a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```xml
<xsl:variable name="stopno" select="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20
  /E1EDK33[E1EDT01/VBELN=current()]
  /E1EDT44/ABLAD"/>
```

Note two points:

- `E1EDT01` is inside the square brackets, which saves the `parent::node()` step.
- The `VBELN` element that was matched by the current template can be accessed as `current()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Heiko :) It works perfectly. The only thing is that if I 'uncomment' my other rule which I want to have processed first to filter out the E1EDT01/VBELN:
<!--    <xsl:template match="/SHPMNT05/IDOC/E1EDT20/E1EDK33/E1EDT01[(VBELN= following-sibling::E1EDT01/VBELN) or (VBELN= ../following-sibling::E1EDK33/E1EDT01/VBELN)]"/> -->
The output is not correct. Can I combine these in 1?

Comment: Adding this other rule does not affect the output for me, at least not for the given input.

Comment: You are correct Heiko. But in the original SAP Idoc I have more elements in E1EDK33. SAP puts all:
<E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667/8/9</VBELN>
</E1EDT01>
In the first E1EDK33. The remaining:
<E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667/9</VBELN>
</E1EDT01>
In the seconde E1EDK33 and the last:
<E1EDT01 SEGMENT="1">
               <VBELN>0081018667</VBELN>
</E1EDT01>
In the last E1EDK33.
My first rule filters these. Bit hard to explain, I'm sorry. Maybe I need to make a separate post?

Comment: A separate post would be good.